# fullCalendar in Rails not matching up right week

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, fullcalendar

I'm trying to implement fullCalendar (using the fullcalendar-rails gem) into my Rails project and although I can display the events on the calendar, the positioning of the events are completely out of whack.
[Example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKJes.png)

The date for this event should be from 02/24 through the 02/28, and it appears that the horizontal positioning is dead on for that, but the vertical alignment (for the week) is way off. If I reload the page the vertical alignment jumps around just a tad too (anywhere from 10px - 100px up and down).

Is there something I'm missing here with the CSS or could it be that my json builder isn't being parsed correctly?

My builder:

```
json.array!(@movies) do |movie|
  json.id movie.id
  json.title movie.name
  json.extract! movie, :description
  json.start movie.start_date
  json.end movie.end_date
  json.url movie_url(movie, format: :html)
end
```

Which produces:

```
[{"id":8,"title":"Test","description":"sldkfjasdflkajsdfasdf","start":"2015-02-24","end":"2015-02-28","url":"http://www.movieman.dev:3000/?format=html"}]
```

My js calling the json:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#movies_calendar').fullCalendar({
      events: '/calendar.json'
    });
});
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Edit: This problem only appears in Chrome, I figure it has to be something in fullCalendar.js/css

Comment: Have you tried it on a very simple page without any of your own or other Rails CSS?

Comment: Yeah, when I've isolated it and hard-coded events into it, it works just fine.

Comment: Another thing I just noticed, this ONLY happens in Chrome. Firefox and Safari work perfectly.

Comment: Whatever is controlling the top position for the fc-event-container is really messing this up in Chrome. Every time I refresh a I get a new position. On first load top:312px - where it should be, then: 171px, 116px, 176px, 138px....What could be changing this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the fix and posting just in case anyone happens to run into this bizarre/rare scenario in the future.

fullCalendar has a section that undos Twitter's Bootstrap box-sizing rules for the positioning of the calendar elements:

```
.fc-view-container *,
.fc-view-container *:before,
.fc-view-container *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
            box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

In my css I had the following:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

By removing the above it fixed the vertical positioning.